# Correlate subquery to joined query

Tags: doctrine, subquery, symfony-1.4

I have this filter addition

```
    $subQuery = $query->createSubquery()
    ->select ('ps.id')
    ->from('Person ps')
    ->innerJoin('ps.JoomlaUser ju')
    ->innerJoin('ju.OrderList o')
    ->innerJoin('o.ItemList oi')
    ->whereIn ('oi.product_id',$value);

    $subSubQuery = $subQuery->createSubquery()
    ->select('oh.order_id')
    ->from ('jos_vm_order_history oh')
    ->addWhere ('oh.order_status_code=?','C')
    ->addWhere ('oh.order_id=o.order_id')   //<-- this doesn't work
    ->orderBy ('oh.date_added desc')
    ->limit(1);

    $subQuery->addWhere('exists (' . $subSubQuery->getDql() . ')');

    $query->addWhere('person_id in (' . $subQuery->getDql() . ')');
```

in which I need to correlate a sub query to table in a joined query. When I execute this I get

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'o.order_id' in 'where clause'
```

How can I get the query alias of the "OrderList" relation that is used in the final query?

Comment: You're trying to mix data between subqueries which is not possible.

Comment: depending on my filter selection I know I could correlate with addWhere ('oh.order_id=j3.order_id'), but I need a generic method to know the alias of that query for OrderList